# How to find what is slow in system and what slows system down?

Tags: 12.04

I just installed 12.04 and want to try make it work by changing whats slow but 1st i need to find what slows it down but how? I want see results and be able to compare between versions.

Answer (score 2):

In the terminal type **top** and it'll show you a list of processes that uses most of the resources (ctrl+alt+T = terminal)

Answer (score 0):

I would start with running system monitor (type 'monitor' in unity) to check which processes are top consumers and what is the load.